# React adding keyboard event navigation to website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add a spacebar control to my audio streaming react made website.
To play/pause i have a button doing the same thing but I want spacebar press should do the same. Doing that with adding event listeners is making trouble as in it gets fired four times while just pressing the spacebar once,(not holding the spacebar).
Please help me how to do the same.
playSongHandler is the function I want to apply to the spacebar press but it is inside the component function, and using addEventListener inside the function maybe also getting triggerred because it is inside the funtion

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's happening without seeing the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)